# Android: Cloning class instance

Tags: android, clone, instance, cloning

I have to build an array of MyView instances (extends WebView). The only difference of each view is the content. So instead of recreating this each time I would like to create one MyView all other instances would be clones of this one.

Is there a way for doing something like that in this case on Android?
Please post a code sample for it.
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You question is a bit vague. You cannot create clones of views according to understanding.
You can use the same xml layout. Or you can update the underlying data of a view and make the view to invalidate so it will be redrawn.